# How to modify post title in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 20 thousands plus posts and all posts have title started with 
**Watch** etc etc...

I want to remove watch from all post title please give the solution how i can do this. Is there any filter which can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Run this query in your phpmyadmin

```
UPDATE wp_posts
   SET post_title = REPLACE(post_title, ' Watch ', '');
```

Where

wp_posts is your post table name

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use the following [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) and search and replace given string in the `post_title` column in the database.